# What can you do when your question is not getting any views?

Tags: support, status-completed

I recently joined gis.stackexchange.com and asked my first question. However after 24 hours my question only received 4 views, while other questions received many more. This made me wonder if there is anything that you can do as the questioner to bring your question under the attention again? So far I couldn't find anything on this topic.

So, what are the options for a user when he/she asked a question, but the question is not getting any or a lot of views?

Comment: It's worthwhile taking a tour of our help system.  Under the section about asking questions you will find your concerns addressed at https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to GIS SE. First and foremost, you can edit and improve your question. A [good question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) almost always yields good answers. Additionally, editing your question bumps it up in the queue so that it gets more exposure.

You can also try adding more detailed [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to your question to draw the right crowd.

If editing your question fails to draw more attention, you can place a [bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on your question once you reach 75 reputation.